# Maximize window on secondary screen

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, display

I am running Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64 bit on a laptop with an Nvidia Geforce GTX 1060.  I am extending the desktop to an external display and am having an annoying issue.  Every time I attempt to maximize the current window on the secondary monitor (currently the laptop monitor) the maximized window snaps to the primary monitor (the external monitor).  Is there a way to maximize the window on the current display?

Comment: This actually appears not to be an issue with Mint but with nVidia and HDMI.

Comment: So, what I have found is that there is actually an issue with dkms - when the kernel is updated, I need to rebuild the display driver.  Still not certain why...